# How to open file in graphical application with dart?

Tags: dart

[open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) only support android and ios.

I want to open any file (as if the user double click it in his file manager) on windows and linux. Here is what I got:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  String executable = 'xdg-open';
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    executable = 'start';
  }
  String myWindowsOrLinuxPath = "${(Platform.environment)['HOME']}${Platform.pathSeparator}my-file.txt";
  Process.run(executable, [myWindowsOrLinuxPath]);
}
```

I have no error on Ubuntu 22.04 and the file does open, but this code doesn't seem so nice.

Is it the right way to do it ?